# bluez 4.101 Device Information Service

Tags: android, ios, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm using the bluez-4.101 stack with kernel 3.0.35 Now I'm able to connect to the peripheral through gatttool, though the connection is not always stable.

When I list the primary services, there is no uuid for the DIS in the output list. That lists the thermometer and battery state like services from the plugins. Why deviceinfo is not listed?

From the code I have seen that the **deviceinfo plugin** doesn't uses the DBUS connection while the other services does use.

In the bluetoothd logs I get '**Not enough free handles to register service**', so the deviceinfo doesn't seem to be registered, while the other services get registered after it. 
What causes this error to come and why there is no **gatt_service_add** function for deviceinfo?

**Edit**: Why does the iOS app(LightBlue) doesn't recognises the advertisement and connect to the device while in android apps the advertisement is detected as iBeacon? 
In android apps also the connection is not always stable?

Comment: What is your peripheral device?

Comment: The peripheral and central are two different custom boards with wl12xx chip from TI

Comment: I have added debug prints to deviceinfo. `deviceinfo_manager_init` calls the `btd_register_device_driver` to which `deviceinfo_device_driver` is passed as an argument that contains the `probe` function for the deviceinfo. I'm not getting any prints from this probe function

Comment: I have implemented the DIS, and able to read its characteristic values from the central device(both on linux platform). But I'm `not able to connect to it from android and iOS mobile apps`. Does it use some other scenario for mobile apps?

Comment: @yousif saeed Sometimes I am not getting the pairing request on the android device after pressing the 'connect' option in the apps like B-BLE and nrf Master control panel. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you had any success with this?

Comment: @chris         For the pairing request, we have found that this seems to be from the app side, we have tried this with a custom app. With this app we are getting the pairing request almost every time. But I'm still not sure why this is happening from our end.